# IC chip which can send a different IR signal from multiple pins

Tags: microcontroller

Hi I have been trying to send different IR signals over multiple pins using an Arduino Uno. I have been using the [**IRremote**](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote) library. It's not possible with Arduino so I am looking for an alternative.

I am looking for a replacement IC chip or microcontroller to use instead of the Arduino Uno. As long as it can send IR signals over 3 or more pins and is programmable.

[**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33556/how-to-choose-a-transmit-pin-in-the-irremote-library-for-an-arduino-uno) and [**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33517/manipulating-3-ir-leds-on-arduino-uno) are questions I asked regarding my IR pin problem if you are interested. It helps explain the situation I'm in.

Bottom line I need any kind of circiut that can send IR signals over multiple pins[image]

Comment: If everything fails, you may want to look for a (small) FPGA with a memory chip (so the FPGA can auto-fetch the logic) to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply do you have some examples of common FPGA's that I could use?

Comment: For example one of the Artix-7 FPGAs from Xilinx (but note they need BGA packaging).